# Why doesn't this code make it possible to store/use a value?

Tags: macros

I wrote this code

```
\documentclass{article}

% make a command called \insertfoo{..} for the user to insert foo
\newcommand{\insertfoo}[1]{%  
\savebox{\boxthatcontainsfoo}{#1}%  
}

% make a command called \showfoo that shows the value for foo
\newcommand{\showfoo}{%
\usebox{\boxthatcontainsfoo}%
}

\insertfoo{somefoo}

\begin{document}
The foo you choose was \showfoo .
end{document}
\end{document}
```

Why do I get a compiling error?

Comment: You have `\newcommand{\}{%` at the start of it all.  That's causing all sorts of problems.  I don't know if that's the real reason for your compilation error because you've only posted a snippet and not a compilable document.

Comment: (See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for more details on MWEs)

Comment: Try without the braces around the box name.  `\savebox` and `\usebox` expect a box, not a braced-group, as the next token (that's my understanding).

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks for pointing that out, but I don't see how this isn't a MWE.

Comment: It's pretty close now, I'll admit.  I should be able to cut-and-paste a single code block into my editor and run tex or latex or pdflatex directly on it without having to add anything else and see the problem.  In this case it's not likely that the class is relevant, but in some cases knowing exactly what packages are loaded is crucial.

Comment: This isn't really a minimal example; but you should say `\insertfoo{somefoo}`, with braces and *not* parentheses.

Comment: I tried ommiting the braces. It didn't work.

Comment: @EdwardStumperd avoidance of typos is one reason we always ask for _complete_ documents, so that the errors you report are from a document that can be processed locally to get the same error. As in Werner's answer. The code fragment starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: @David Ok, I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This* is a MWE that works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% make a command called \insertfoo{..} for the user to insert foo
\newsavebox{\boxthatcontainsfoo}
\newcommand{\insertfoo}[1]{%  
  \savebox{\boxthatcontainsfoo}{#1}%  
}

% make a command called \showfoo that shows the value for foo
\newcommand{\showfoo}{%
  \usebox{\boxthatcontainsfoo}%
}
\begin{document}
\insertfoo{somefoo}
The foo you chose was \showfoo.

\insertfoo{some other foo}
The foo you chose was \showfoo.
\end{document}
```

You need to define the box that you use to store the content (`\boxthatcontainsfoo`), but also use `\insertfoo{...}` when passing arguments to the macro, not `\insertfoo(...)`.

It is possible to modify `\insertfoo` to function with (round) brackets if needed.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.